# What do Gandharvas look like?

Tags: scripture, demon

The closest thing to a description of them is the description of Kali, which I couldn't find an exact reference for.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_(demon)

Comment: Related question with references to help explore on them https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/who-are-gandharvas